# if url contains string, do something, else do another or add paramter to console which runs protractor

Tags: angularjs, string, protractor

```
    if(browser.getCurrentUrl().
toString.contain('local')){//if it is local,do something.if it is not local, i need to do another things
    //do something
    }
    else{

    //do another
    }
```

I need to get url and check if it contains local. If it has local, i need to do operations for local. Else, i will do another operations.

I cant do this with expect because it will give failure if is was not matched.

So i need to use string operatipns.

But none of those worked:

```
browser.getCurrentUrl().toString.contain('local')
browser.getCurrentUrl().toString.contains('local')
browser.getCurrentUrl().contain('local')
browser.getCurrentUrl().contains('local')
```

error is

**toString.contain is not a function**

**ANOTHER SOLUTION**

While running protractor from console,

```
gulp protractor
```

i run with this.

SO if i can do like this:

```
  gulp protractor local
```

or for another usages,

```
 gulp protractor testmachine
```

it will be better. It can record that parameter to a variable so i will access that variable

```
  if(paramter.equals="local"){//if it is local,do something.if it is not local, i need to do another things
    //do something
    }
    else{

    //do another
    }
```

i can also do something like that instead of **currenturl**

**if(logoutPageObject.baseUrl.toString.contain("local")){** because **baseurl** variable can say if i am on local or not. but also this doesnot work.

Answer (score 1):

`browser.getCurrentUrl()` will return you a promise and not a string. First resolve the promise and use the exact URL for the validation.

```
browser.getCurrentUrl().then(function(url){
    if(url.indexOf("local") >= 0 ){
     console.log("url contains local")
   }else{
    console.log("do something else")
  }
})
```

Comment: it always go to do something else. url is http://localhost:8080/ so i changed to if(url.indexOf("localhost") >= 0 ){ but still goes to do something else.

Comment: have to tried console.log(url) and check whether correct url is displayed?

Comment: yes. url.toString() or url shows output as data in console. because getcurrenturl shows unresolved functon when i go mouse over it. wwhy?  i can also do something like that instead of currenturl f(logoutPageObject.baseUrl.toString.contain("local")){ because baseurl variable can say if i am on local or not. but also this doesnot work.